# Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio

I've migrated to Android Studio 2.0 Preview and I'm getting, no matter what I do, :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\jdk7\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Any help indeed much appreciated!

Comment: Are you not getting any other error messages?

Comment: you are well within 65k limit ? or are you using any large libraries

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle script, set the dexOptions.javaMaxHeapSize configuration to whatever value you need:

```
android {
//snip
//add this into your existing 'android' block
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
//snip
}
```

[Source](https://metova.com/blog/dev/overhead-limit-exceeded/)