# Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. ionic3/cordova6.3.0/node

Tags: ionic3, cordova-android

getting error build failed with following config. I've installed following plugins to my project. I tried these two links, but it did not work for me.
[#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962817/execution-failed-for-task-transformclasseswithdexfordebug) and [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437117/execution-failed-for-task-transformclasseswithdexfordebug-ionic-3-please-hel).
getting error build failed with following config. I've installed following plugins to my project. I tried these two links, but it did not work for me.
[#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962817/execution-failed-for-task-transformclasseswithdexfordebug) and [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437117/execution-failed-for-task-transformclasseswithdexfordebug-ionic-3-please-hel).
getting error build failed with following config. I've installed following plugins to my project. I tried these two links, but it did not work for me.
[#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962817/execution-failed-for-task-transformclasseswithdexfordebug) and [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437117/execution-failed-for-task-transformclasseswithdexfordebug-ionic-3-please-hel).

can anyone guide to me to the correct solution?

### Console error trace:

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 45.774 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.pro
cess.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.
DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice
/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
(node:9988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejec
tion id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.pro
cess.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.
DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice
/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
```

---

### BuildConfig.java

```
/**
 * Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY
 */
package org.apache.cordova;

public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "org.apache.cordova";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
}
```

---

getting error in build config java file :

```
[Java] The declared package "org.apache.cordova" does not match the expected package "CordovaLib.build.generated.source.buildConfig.debug.org.apache.cordova"
```

---

```
card.io.cordova.mobilesdk 2.1.0 "CardIO"
com-badrit-base64 0.2.0 "Base64"
com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk 3.5.0 "PayPalMobile"
com.synconset.imagepicker 2.1.10 "ImagePicker"
cordova-clipboard 1.1.1 "Clipboard"
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 1.11.0 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-android-support-v4 21.0.1 "Android Support v4"
cordova-plugin-app-update 1.5.2 "AppUpdate"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-appminimize 1.0 "AppMinimize"
cordova-plugin-appversion 1.0.0 "App Version"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.7 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.2 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.9.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-filechooser 1.0.1 "File Chooser"
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.0.2 "FilePath"
cordova-plugin-filepicker 1.1.4 "File Picker"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.2.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 2.0.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.16 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-market 1.2.0 "Market"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid 1.3.2 "UniqueDeviceID"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.3.2 "SocialSharing"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"





>ionic info
cli packages: (C:\Users\UserXx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.0.1
    Node              : v8.9.0
    npm               : 3.10.10
    OS                : Windows 8.1

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\UserXx\android-sdks

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this command and then build/run your ionic project.

**cordova clean android**

It should succesfully build/run after you execute this command.

Comment: I fixed it by just switching the directory. Cloning my project again and building it. Seems like one of the directories/files generated in project when building my project may have gotten corrupted. Deleting all generated files in my project solved the problem. Just like cleaning android using @CodeMine solution.